# Node.js multiple requests at same time and one result returning

Tags: node.js, request

Multiple users can call requests at the same time, so I want to do if one user calls to request and calculation of results is being started then when another user calls the same request results calculation is not being started, but wait for results which were asked for the first user. In other words, the calculation of the result should be started only if it is not 'locked' by another user, if it is - then waits for the result.

**Edited**

**Code:**
[image]

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: What does `GetResults` do? Is it really synchronous? If yes and it's a long running op, your risk blocking the event loop, meaning that no requests will be served until the function has finished executing.

Comment: @eol it is just a pseudo-code example, but yes GetResults would be a long operation

Comment: So it is in fact `async` and returns a promise? You should make this visible in your example then, e.g. `const result = await GetResults()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To guarantee that the result is not calculated multiple times for concurrent requests, you need to implement some kind of locking mechanism (as you expected).

Here's a very basic example of what your code could look like, that simply pushes requests to a queue if the mutex is currently locked. If not the result gets calculated and for all pending requests a response with the calculated value will be sent:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

class Mutex {
    constructor() {
        this.queue = [];
        this.locked = false;
    }

    lock() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (this.locked) {
                this.queue.push([resolve, reject]);
            } else {
                this.locked = true;
                resolve();
            }
        });
    }

    release(value) {
        if (this.queue.length > 0) {
            const [resolve, reject] = this.queue.shift();
            resolve(value);
        } else {
            this.locked = false;
        }
    }
}

const getResultsMutex = new Mutex();

function getResults() {
    return new Promise((resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(Math.random()), 5000);
    }))
}

function sendResponse(result, req, res) {
    res.send("The result is " + result);
}

app.get('/getresults', async (req, res) => {
    let result = await getResultsMutex.lock();
    if (!result) {
        result = await getResults();
    }
    sendResponse(result, req, res);
    getResultsMutex.release(result);
});

app.listen(4000, function () {
    console.log("Server is running at port 4000");
});
```

Comment: weird, the first time when I call it successfully returns a result if I call it again then it gets stuck

Comment: it works now, but If I call a request while another request is executed then they return different results, I need the same results for both requests

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your current code? I cannot reproduce this, I always get the same results as expected.

Comment: My code is the same as yours, just ran on a different port. Added pictures with code and results

Comment: @adska: Ok, so I've changed the code quite a bit to a custom mutex. Can you try again with this code please?

Comment: same problem and looks like the first request return result faster. (I attached an animated gif to the question.)

Comment: Can you try disabling cache in chrome (F12 -> Network Tab -> Disable Cache)? Or try it with two different browsers? Here's how it works on my machine: https://streamable.com/co9ad5

Comment: "Disable Cache" helped, it works as expected, thank you so much

Comment: Happy to help, please don't forget to also accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on the left, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
/** @type {[express.Request, express.Response][]} */
let requestQueue = [];

/**
 * @param {express.Request} req 
 * @param {express.Response} res 
 */
async function processRequest( req, res ) {
    var result = await GetResults();
    res.end(result);
    if (requestQueue.length !== 0) processRequest.apply(requestQueue.shift());
}

app.get("/getresults", (req, res) => {
    if (requestQueue.length !== 0) return requestQueue.push([req, res]);
    processRequest(req, res);
});
```

**EDIT:** If they should all receive the same result, then this code:

```js
/** @type {Promise} */
let requestPromise = null;

app.get("/getresults", (req, res) => {
    if (requestPromise === null) requestPromise = GetResults().finally(() => requestPromise = null); // returns a promise
    res.send(await requestPromise);
});
```

Comment: the first code gets stuck. the second code is something wrong, I am not able to run it